# MacOS fopenmp in Qt creator: Using openMP

Tags: c++, macos, qt, clang, openmp

I'm trying to use openMP in a QT project in Qt Creator. I have a project set up with the following QMake flags `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -fopenmp -Wall~`
`LIBS += -fopenmp`. After googling around for a couple days, I've come across suggestions mentioning to use different compilers or using `Xclang` and I have tried these methods: using clang++, clang, GCC, LLVM to try and compile but it just results in the same error for all, mentioning `clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp`

I'm wondering if there is any way to get this compile?

Comment: On macOS the `gcc` command is just an alias to `clang`. You have to install a genuine `gcc` version. The easiest ways are either from MacPorts or HomeBrew. `gcc` has a wide support of OpenMP.

Comment: @PierU Thanks for the reply! I installed gcc by doing `brew install gcc`

Answer (score -1):

Here's a step-by-step workaround for you:

1. **Get OpenMP through Homebrew**:

   Before anything else, make sure you have the OpenMP library on your system. If it's missing, give Homebrew a nudge:

   ```bash
   brew install libomp
   ```

   This will get you the LLVM flavor of OpenMP, which is a good thing.
2. **Tweak that .pro file**:

   You'll need to give the compiler a hint about the newly installed OpenMP:

   ```
   QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp
   LIBS += -lomp
   ```

   That fancy `-Xpreprocessor` flag? It's basically telling the compiler, "Hey, pass that `-fopenmp` to the preprocessor, will ya?"
3. **Pick the right tools**:

   If things still seem off, think about installing the complete LLVM suite. This package has a friendly version of Clang that gets along with OpenMP:

   ```bash
   brew install llvm
   ```

   Post-installation, head over to Qt Creator. Navigate to `Tools > Options > Kits`, and ensure you're pointing to the Clang versions you just got via Homebrew. Typically, they chill out at `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang` and its sibling, `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++`.
4. **Guide the paths**:

   Sometimes, you've gotta handhold the compiler and linker to make sure they locate the necessary headers and libraries. Update your .pro file:

   ```
   INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/opt/llvm/include
   LIBS += -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib
   ```
5. **Give it another go**:

   With all these changes in place, invoke `qmake` and give your project another spin.

Wrapping it up, the main hiccup here is Apple's native Clang, which isn't the best pal of OpenMP. But with some Homebrew magic and a few tweaks, your Qt project should be harmonizing with OpenMP in no time. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I followed your steps and I get the error `library 'omp' not found' I did do `brew install libomp`. Was I supposed to do something else as well?

Comment: Try one of the following:
1. **Check if the library is correctly installed**
`ls /usr/local/Cellar/libomp`
2. **Try to uninstall and reinstall the library**
`brew uninstall libomp`
`brew install libomp`
3. **Try to symlink your library forcefully**
`brew link --overwrite libomp`
4. **Set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH**
`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libomp/{version}/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`
5. **Tweak compiler options**
Try and tell the linker explicitly to use openMP by adding the line `QMAKE_LFLAGS += -fopenmp` to your .pro file.
Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Much easier: use a genuine gcc

Comment: @PierU how do you install genuine gcc? all guides for installing gcc on Mac just say to use `brew install gcc` but this is not the genuine version

Comment: By "genuine version" I mean not an alias/link to another compiler, as it is on macOS by default. The version installed by Homebrew is definitely a "genuine" one.